# How to make a Google Translate REST API call in PHP for multiple strings

Tags: php, arrays, rest, google-translate

I'm following the documentation from the [Google Translation API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/translate), specifically for the `translate` method that accepts one or more parameter(s) `q` for the value(s) you want to translate and parameter `target` which accepts the language you wish to translate the value(s) in.

I have a PHP function that makes calls to the REST API and it works:

```
function google_translate() {
    $api_key = 'my api key';
    $url = 'https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=' . $api_key;

    $form = [
        'q' => 'Hello World!',
        'target' => 'fr',
    ];

    $ch = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $form );

    $response = curl_exec( $ch );

    curl_close( $ch );

    $response = json_decode( $response );
    var_dump( $response );
}
google_translate();
```

This works well, however, the documentation states that you can provide additional strings by simply using multiple `q` parameters. I have tried this on on a REST client without using PHP and it works i.e. providing multiple `q` parameters in the same call with different string values and it returns translations for all, however, I have no idea how I can make this work with PHP since a PHP array can only contain unique keys.

How can I rework my function so I only have to make one call instead of multiple for string translations? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding q in querystring?

```
<?php
$apiKey = 'Moo!';
$text = 'Hello world!';
$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=' . $apiKey . '&q=' . rawurlencode($text) . '&source=en&target=fr';

$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($handle);                 
$responseDecoded = json_decode($response, true);
curl_close($handle);

echo 'Source: ' . $text . '<br>';
echo 'Translation: ' . $responseDecoded['data']['translations'][0]['translatedText'];
```

?>